# Explain python list comprehension technique

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Can someone please explain this bit of code please.

```
>>> guest=['john','sue','chris']
>>> [(a,b,c) for a in guest for b in guest for c in guest]
```

With these results...

```
[('john', 'john', 'john'), ('john', 'john', 'sue'), ('john', 'john', 'chris'), ('john', 'sue', 'john'), ('john', 'sue',
'sue'), ('john', 'sue', 'chris'), ('john', 'chris', 'john'), ('john', 'chris', 'sue'), ('john', 'chris', 'chris'), ('sue
', 'john', 'john'), ('sue', 'john', 'sue'), ('sue', 'john', 'chris'), ('sue', 'sue', 'john'), ('sue', 'sue', 'sue'), ('s
ue', 'sue', 'chris'), ('sue', 'chris', 'john'), ('sue', 'chris', 'sue'), ('sue', 'chris', 'chris'), ('chris', 'john', 'j
ohn'), ('chris', 'john', 'sue'), ('chris', 'john', 'chris'), ('chris', 'sue', 'john'), ('chris', 'sue', 'sue'), ('chris'
, 'sue', 'chris'), ('chris', 'chris', 'john'), ('chris', 'chris', 'sue'), ('chris', 'chris', 'chris')]
```

I understand the (a,b,c) is constructing a three value tuple but I don't understand whats going on with the loops. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a nested list comprehension, and you can expand the loops in the same order they appear in the comprehension to understand what's happening:

```
result = []
for a in guest:
    for b in guest:
        for c in guest:
            # yield (a,b,c)
            result.append((a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if the code is rewritten this way you'll be able to understand:

```
guest=['john','sue','chris']
three_guest_list = []    

for a in guest:
    for b in guest:
        for c in guest:
            three_guest_list.append((a,b,c))

print three_guest_list
```

The list comprehension is just a way to express the loops more succinctly.

Hope this helps!